# Node.js, как запустить автоматически выполняющийся скрипт по времени?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

- Есть сервер на nodejs, входной файл server.js запускаю на сервере через forever start
- Есть скрипт который парсит с сайта донора информацию

Хотел сделать чтобы парсинг происходил раз в полчаса, использовал пакет 'node-shedule'
Но понял, что сделал неправильно засунув код в server.js, т.е. каждый пользователь зашедший на сайт запускал скрипт парсинга.

Как сделать скрипт выполняющийся сервером (т.е. даже если на сайте нет посещений) через каждые полчаса, типа - крон или или добавлять как-то в очередь задача?

Если можно, то поделитесь примером.

Заранее, спасибо

Comment: Либо в крон самой системый засунуть запуск скрипта, либо запустить скрипт, в котором вы запустите таск с помощью https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron

Comment: @Suvitruf, а не лучше ли вывести скрипт парсинга в отдельный модуль и запускать его через `setInterval`?

Comment: @Дмытрык  github.com/kelektiv/node-cron удобнее, чем`setInterval`, как по мне.